# Matplotlib colorbar forces a centered axis to be left aligned

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use matplotlib colorbars it seems to take what would have been a centered axis and force it to become left align.

I'm adding a colorbar like this:

```
def colorbar(scalars, colors):
    """ adds a color bar next to the axes """
    printDBG('colorbar()')
    # Parameters
    xy, width, height = _axis_xy_width_height()
    orientation = ['vertical', 'horizontal'][0]
    TICK_FONTSIZE = 8
    #
    listed_cmap = scores_to_cmap(scalars, colors)
    # Create scalar mappable with cmap
    sorted_scalars = sorted(scalars)
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=listed_cmap)
    sm.set_array(sorted_scalars)
    # Use mapable object to create the colorbar
    COLORBAR_SHRINK = .42  # 1
    COLORBAR_PAD = .01  # 1
    COLORBAR_ASPECT = np.abs(20 * height / (width))  # 1
    printDBG('[df] COLORBAR_ASPECT = %r' % COLORBAR_ASPECT)

    cb = plt.colorbar(sm, orientation=orientation, shrink=COLORBAR_SHRINK,
                      pad=COLORBAR_PAD, aspect=COLORBAR_ASPECT)
    # Add the colorbar to the correct label
    axis = cb.ax.xaxis if orientation == 'horizontal' else cb.ax.yaxis
    position = 'bottom' if orientation == 'horizontal' else 'right'
    axis.set_ticks_position(position)
    axis.set_ticks([0, .5, 1])
    cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=TICK_FONTSIZE)
```

I'm not sure if there is anything I can do to prevent this behavior.